# how to check if the value of a column exists in list value of another column in hive sql

Tags: sql, hive

I have the table A as below:

| id | november_product | december_product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | A | A,C,D |
| 123 | B | A,C,D |
| 456 | C | E,F,G |

December_product is list values, Each value separated by commas. I want to check if value of 'November_product' column esists in 'December_product' column and show value of 'november product' not exists in 'december_product'?

### Expect result:

| id | november_product | december_product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | B | A,C,D |
| 456 | C | E,F,G |

I tried exist and in but not success, so I do not have any methods to handle this problem

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I do not have any ways to write code

Comment: Please share the expected result? `I want to check if value of November_product column esists in December_product column and show value of november product'not exists in december_product` << Do you want to add another column? What should it fill? yes/no?value exists? value not exists?

Comment: I shared on the post on Expect result